# Euler equation for a system with integral constraints

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The question is:

Find all the curves $y(x)$
with $y(−1) = y(1) = 0$ that extremise the functional $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 + (y′)^2  dx$, subject to the
constraint $\int_{-1}^1y^2 dx = 1$.

I've used a Lagrangian multiplier and found the Euler-Lagrange equation which reduces to $$y'' - \lambda y = 0$$

And then that gives three different solutions for $y$ depending on the sign of $\lambda$. The problem is that when I try to solve for the coefficients using the constraint and the boundary conditions, it keeps reducing to the trivial $y=0$, which makes me think I'm going wrong somewhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Note that $x^2$ term plays no role in the extremization process, so we'll drop it from now on. Also for later convenience, let us shift the interval from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,2]$. Moreover, compared to OP, we take the opposite sign convention for the [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda$.
2. The constraint 
   $$\int_0^2 \! dx~ y^2~=~1\tag{1}$$
   can be viewed as wave function normalization in quantum mechanics.
3. The Dirichlet boundary conditions (BC) 
   $$ y(0)~=~0~=~y(2) \tag{2} $$
   corresponds to the [infinite potential well/particle in a box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box).
4. OP's functional becomes the energy functional
   $$E[y,\lambda]~:=~\int_0^2 \! dx ~y^{\prime 2} +\lambda\left( 1-\int_0^2 \! dx~y^2\right)
   ~=~\lambda + \int_0^2 \! dx \underbrace{\left(y^{\prime 2} -\lambda y^2\right)}_{=:~L} . \tag{3}$$
5. The [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) becomes the [TISE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)
   $$ -y^{\prime\prime}~=~\lambda y.\tag{4} $$
6. All the solutions to the EL eq. (4), BCs (2) & constraint (1) are the 
   energy eigenstates
   $$y_n(x)~=~\sin\frac{n\pi x}{2}, \qquad \lambda_n~=~\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)^2,\qquad n~\in\mathbb{N}.\tag{5} $$
7. The value of the functional at the stationary points are the energy
   $$ S[y_n,\lambda_n]~=~\ldots~=~\lambda_n .\tag{6}$$
8. The minimum/ground state energy is given by the $n=1$ solution. There is no maximum energy.